# Electron: How to minimize a window from a rendered process

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

**Scenario**

I have a window and it has an `add task button` that is opening a window. Everytime user clicks on it, it opens a window. I have a button on `add task window` that minimize it. How to implement this minimize button?

**Code**

I am able to `close` `maximize` window by using the code below:

```
var winclose = function () {
    window.close();
}

var winmaximize = function () {
    window.moveTo(0, 0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
}
```

However, I am not able to find any function that can minimize a window from rendered process.

Please help, many thanks;

Note:

*Browsers do not provide a function to devs to minimize them. but here
is a different scenario. Here I am using chromium provided by Electronjs. So, there must be a way to do so as we are developing a desktop application*

Dummy Download link: [download from OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=628606F852453EF0!11473&authkey=!ACoDxbjyxrqkpM4&ithint=folder%2Chtml)

Comment: @mnwsmit browsers do not provide a function to devs to minimize them. but here is a different senario. Here I am using chromium provided by Electron js. So, there must be a way to do so as we are developing an desktop application.

Comment: @mnwsmit I hope you can remove the duplicate tag

Comment: So, to be clear, do you want to minimise a `BrowserWindow` instance from within that instance? I.e. you want to minimise the window via JavaScript of that window?

Comment: I apologise for being unclear. Let me give an example. I have a window and it has an `add task button` that is opening a window. Everytime user clicks on it, it opens a window. I have a button on `add task window` that minimize it. How to implement this minimize button?

Comment: I assume the window is being created in the `main` process? Do you have a reference to newly created windows in the `main` process?

Comment: The windows are getting created from rendered process itself. Right now, I am not storing the window's reference in any array.... should I?? @OwenAyres

Comment: These `window` instances you are creating are definitely new `BrowserWindow` instances, right? You should be keeping a reference to them somehow. You can use this reference to call `.minimize()` directly on it.

Comment: yes. they are the instances of `BrowserWindow` and even if I store them in an array as ref. but how will I minimize as the minimize button is on the `add task window` not on the `home` window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114107/discussion-between-owen-ayres-and-vikas-bansal).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can call [`minimize()`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appexitexitcode) on the respective `BrowserWindow` instance. The question is how to best get access to this instance and this, in turn, depends on how you open the windows and where your minimize button is. From your example, I take it that the minimize button is actually in the window you want to close, in that case you can just minimize the focused window, because to when a user clicks the button inside it, the window should currently have the focus:

```
const { remote } = require('electron')
remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().minimize();
```

Alternatively you can use `BrowserWindow.fromId()` to get access to the window in question if, for example, you want to minimize the task window from the other window.

Comment: how can I set this id at the time of creation?

Comment: Hey there is breaking change on electron remote, so the remote object moved from module `electron` to `@electron/remote`. [Breaking changes info here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#removed-remote-module)

Comment: So you can use it now by `import { BrowserWindow } from "@electron/remote";`

Answer (score 10):

Old thread but it should be noted that the remote module is seen as a security issue and its use is discouraged (see [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#15-disable-the-remote-module)).
It is also deprecated as-is in electron 12 (see [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes)).

Instead, you can just send an command via IPC to invoke the minimize.

From the renderer:

```
ipcRenderer.send('minimize')
```

In main:

```
ipcMain.on('minimize', () => {
  win.minimize()
  // or depending you could do: win.hide()
})
```

You can also just make a toggle (in main):

```
ipcMain.on('minimize', () => {
  win.isMinimized() ? win.restore() : win.minimize()
  // or alternatively: win.isVisible() ? win.hide() : win.show()
})
```

For dynamically made windows (as noted in other answers and as it appears to be the use case) you can use (in place of 'win'):

```
BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()
```

This creates an issue with toggling if you have more than one window (which is the point) but you can use `BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()` and iterate if you want to restore a specific window from outside the current renderer process (say by ID). Don't know why you would want to do this but I include it for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

In case you stumble upon this thread and are using electron vue you can use `this.$electron.remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().minimize();` from directly inside your renderer.

Comment: this.$electron.remote variable is not defined in my project so I am getting error like can not get BrowserWindow property for undefined

Comment: @JigneshGothadiya Hey Jignesh, I'm not very familiar with the documentation but I'd presume by now they may have changed the electron api for the renderer, check the docs. If not then you've more than likely got something else wrong with your code than this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```js
const { remote } = require('electron')
remote.getCurrentWindow().minimize();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Minimizing a screen from the renderer is very easy.** Using the remote object we can be able to minimize the screen from the renderer. Suppose you have a button that triggers the screen minimization when it is clicked. Bellow is a function that does that.

```
const handleMinimise =()=>{
    remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().minimize();
}
```

**But first of all you have to require remote from electron as follows**

```
const electron = require("electron")
const remote = electron.remote
```

**Or As follow**

```
const { remote } = require("electron")
```