# Electron v1.7: Close, Maximize and Maximize

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to build a Simple App having Close, Maximize and Minimize buttons.

The problem with the application is that the Close, Maximize and Minimize are not working properly. The `console.log()` when the buttons are clicked, is functioning properly and displaying the proper messages, however, it is not performing the actual Close, Maximize and Minimize operations.

Also, not that in the CSS, I have added `-webkit-app-region: drag;` for the header but added `-webkit-app-region: no-drag;` for options, i.e., buttons.

Attaching a screenshot.

[image]

The content of driver index.js is:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const url = require('url');

let win = null;

function boot() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 640,
        height: 480,
        frame: false
    });
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null;
    });
}

app.on('ready', boot);
```

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background: #353535;
    color: black;
    align-self: stretch;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

#content {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: black;
    align-items: center;
}

.option {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
    
}

.option:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Sample App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <header>
                <div class="option" id="close">X</div>
                <div class="option" id="minimize">-</div>
                <div class="option" id="maximize">=</div>         
            </header>               
        </div>
        
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, the contents of script.js is

```
    const {remote} = require('electron');

document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', closeWindow);
document.getElementById('minimize').addEventListener('click', minimizeWindow);
document.getElementById('maximize').addEventListener('click', maximizeWindow);



function closeWindow () {        
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
}

function minimizeWindow () {   
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.minimize();
}

function maximizeWindow () {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow()
    window.isMaximized() ? window.unmaximize() : window.maximize();
}
```

Comment: Do you receive any error when you click the buttons? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37721711/7434393) answer `getFocusedWindow` should work, have you tried that?

Comment: in a project am working on , i implemented something like this, but the way i did it, was whenever the user clicks the close button, it sends a message using ipc to the main process, the main process just have to call `window.maximize()`

Comment: @kontrollanten, That answer fixed my problem. Please write an answer on it so that it helps everyone. If you don't want to write. Please reply, I would write the answer myself. :)

Comment: @0.sh The problem was solved when I used `var window = remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();`, followed by using `window.close();`, `window.minimize();`, and `window.isMaximized() ? window.unmaximize() : window.maximize();`. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be fixed by using [getFocusedWindow](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#browserwindowgetfocusedwindow) instead of [getCurrentWindow](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md#remotegetcurrentwindow).

In your script.js file, update the the functions, `closeWindow()`, `minimizeWindow()` and `maximizeWindow()`, as:

```
const {remote} = require('electron');

document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', closeWindow);
document.getElementById('minimize').addEventListener('click', minimizeWindow);
document.getElementById('maximize').addEventListener('click', maximizeWindow);

/*
  getFocusedWindow() may return null.
  If a user uses global keyboard shortcut to trigger 
  minimizeWindow, there may not be any window that 
  is focused right now
*/ 
const getWindow = () => remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();

function closeWindow () {
    getWindow().close();
}

function minimizeWindow () {  
    getWindow().minimize();
}

function maximizeWindow () {
    const window = getWindow();
    window.isMaximized() ? window.unmaximize() : window.maximize();
}
```

The reason why `getFocusedWindow()` works instead of `getCurrentWindow()` can be explained by an experienced developer.

Comment: Is there any way that `var window = remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();` can be only written once?

Comment: Great! And just so you know getFocusedWindow() may return null. If a user uses global keyboard shortcut to trigger minimizeWindow, there may not be any window that is focused right now.

Answer (score 1):

If this didn't work for you:

```
window.isMaximized() ? window.unmaximize() : window.maximize();
```

Try this instead:

```
  function maximizeWindow () {
    var window = remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
    window.setFullScreen(!window.isFullScreen());
  }
```

Comment: Isn't full screen different from maximize?  With maximize, the title bar is displayed, for example