# maximize/unmaximize doesn't work on electron when resizable: false

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am developing a desktop app by Electron. Which are frame-less window and I write a JS maximize/unmaximize button which is working good?

```
<button class="max" onclick="MaxUnMax();">&nbsp;</button>
```

**JS**

```
function MaxUnMax () {
   const remote = require('electron').remote
   const { BrowserWindow } = remote;
   var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
   if (!window.isMaximized()) {
      window.maximize();
   } else {
      window.unmaximize();
   }
}
```

But when I disable the resize ability (by `resizable: false` on main.js) the maximize/unmaximize button doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/46882965/7434393 ? Ie, try to use `getFocusedWindow` instead of `getCurrentWindow`. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: no, when I use this it's stop working !

Answer (score 0):

i got a similar issue and i found this solution:

instead of using`window.isMaximized()` i used `window.isFullScreen()`

and for `window.maximize()` and `window.unmaximize()` i used `window.setFullScreen(true)` and `window.setFullScreen(false);`

and it works for me even with `resizable: false`

solution 1:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const { BrowserWindow } = remote;
function MaxUnMax () {
   var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
   if (!window.isFullScreen()) {
      window.setFullScreen(true);
   } else {
      window.setFullScreen(false);
   }
}
```

solution 2:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const { BrowserWindow } = remote;
function MaxUnMax () {
   var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
   window.setFullScreen(!win.isFullScreen());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use setFullScreen(true) instead of maximize()

```
win.setFullScreen(true);
```