# How to maximize and minimize window in electron without the remote module

Tags: jquery, electron, minimize, maximize

I am trying to create an **electron** app but I cant understand how to use the remote module by
`require('@electron/remote/');`

I am able to close the window by `window.close();`

> But I cant understand how to **minimize** and **maximize** the window.

> I would like to use **jquery** to ***maximize, restore, minimize and unmaximize***

So please answer me if there is a solution and try to give me an easy explanation of ipc.

***Thanks in Advance.***.

Comment: Maybe it's worth looking at Electron's IPC? I believe they have this exact use-case as an example in their documentation, but I am not sure.

Comment: I tried learning ipc and I am but if there is a better solution pls provide me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current browser window in the renderer in Electron 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070320/how-to-get-the-current-browser-window-in-the-renderer-in-electron-14)

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46882965/4698373) and let us know if targeting the windows with `getFocusedWindow()` makes it work better.

Comment: Remote is not supported in Electron v14. So I need a better approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just having the same problem today and I managed to find the solution. The Electron team does not want you to use remote because well.. It's bad.

Please PLEASE PLEASE read everything carefully!

The best solution is using ipc. Don't worry. It's not that complicated when you do it like this.

Note: look for `//------------------------` for where the code is pasted

This is probably what your main process looks like (main process is where the window is created) Just an explanation, no copy-paste here.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, electron } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const createWindow = () => {
        // Create the browser window.
        const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        minWidth: 1000,
        minHeight: 480,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true, 
        contextIsolation: false,
        },
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

So the first step put stuff in your renderer process (the script attached to the html document)

```
//--------------------------------------------
const electron = require("electron");
const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;

const togmax = document.getElementById("togmax");

togmax.addEventListener("click", function() {
    ipc.send("toggle-maximize-window");
});
//--------------------------------------------
```

Next, put this in your `const create window = () => {...`

```
//--------------------------------------------
const ipc = require("electron").ipcMain;
//--------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------
ipc.on("toggle-maximize-window", function(event) {
    if(mainWindow.isMaximized()) {
        mainWindow.unmaximize();
    } else {
        mainWindow.maximize();
    }
});
//--------------------------------------------
```

This is what your main script should look like afterwards.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, electron } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
//---------------------------------------------
const ipc = require("electron").ipcMain;
//---------------------------------------------

const createWindow = () => {
    // Create the browser window.
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        minWidth: 1000,
        minHeight: 480,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true, 
            contextIsolation: false,
        },
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();


 //----------------------------------------------------------------
    ipc.on("toggle-maximize-window", function(event) {
        if(mainWindow.isMaximized()) {
            mainWindow.unmaximize();
        } else {
            mainWindow.maximize();
        }
    });
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
};
```

To sum it up, you're putting in `nodeIntergration: true` so you can use "require" in the script on your HTML. You're using the script with ipcRenderer to send message to the main process (ipcMain) and `ipc.on(...)`
means that when it receive a message, it does whatever is between the brackets. The reason we pasted the code *inside* where the main window is created, is because we want the functions that the remote module has.
with that piece of code there, you can do things like `mainWindow.maximize()`, `mainWindow.minimize()`, check if its maximized, and everything that remote allows you to do. if you want more, check out this link. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window/#event-maximize It shows you all the things you can do.

And boom you're done. There was only 3 things to paste in so you're good.
Make sure to check out the Electron docs after this. I'm nice so I spoon-feed you code but make sure to learn more after you hit a roadblock!

Comment: Thanks (but I saw your answer way before and I did not reply ) So I knew php more than node that time. But now I am not developing an app instead a website. Well, main thing - Thank you Very Very much!

Comment: It fells you took quite some time writing all this! Thanks for your effort and time!