# Electron, minimizing the screen

Tags: javascript, electron, minimize

I'm pretty new here, I have a project in Electron, and I want to do my own minimize/maximize, close buttons. And my minimize/maximize buttons don't work that well. I've been through several topics asking the question, but it still won't work.
When I first click, it maximize the window, but when I click again, it won't minimize, and so it stay in the state "window is maximized" in the if/else.

Even when I start to make my own boolean to force the function, it understand when it goes maximized. But it won't go to the other state.

Here's a sample of the code

```
  const remote = require('electron').remote;

  let screenExit = document.getElementById("close-btn")
  let screenSize = document.getElementById("size-btn")

//Close Windows

screenExit.addEventListener( "click", e => {
  let window = remote.getCurrentWindow()
  window.close()
 } )

//Minimize & Maximize

 $('#size-btn').click(function() {
  let window = remote.getCurrentWindow()
  if(window.isMaximized()){
      window.restore();
      console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAH")
  }else{
      window.maximize();
      console.log("This sh** gone work ._.")
  }
});
```

In the console, it keeps loging me "AAAAAAAAAAAAH" since it won't go to the other case. Even if I do my own boolean.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: On __which environment/OS__ do you test (Linux) ? The docs say: [minimize only works on Win/MacOS](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winisminimizable-macos-windows).

Comment: Did you have a look into [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696350/electron-how-to-minimize-a-window-from-a-rendered-process) where answer suggests that exact _instance (ID)_ of `BrowserWindow` matters. Maybe you can [listen on your window-events](http://robmayhew.com/listening-for-events-from-windows-in-electron-tutorial/) and add some debug-logging to respective minimize/maximize-handlers.

Comment: @hc_dev on Windows, no problem for this
I'll try at home the focusedWindow method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got news

the method ".isMaximized" from electron don't work that much, so the app don't see if it is max or minimized. Once you know that, you apply unmaximized in a case, maximized in the other (thanks to @Khokim Mamarasulov), and you just do a boolean that change once you put one or another value, here's a sample.

```
//Minimize & Maximize
 $('#size-btn').click(function() {
  let window = remote.getCurrentWindow()
  if(changeState == true){
      window.unmaximize();
      console.log ("beforeUnmax :",changeState)
      changeState = false
      console.log ("afterUnmax :",changeState)
  }else{
      window.maximize();
      console.log ("beforeMax :",changeState)
      changeState = true
      console.log ("afterMax :",changeState)

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.unmaximize()` or `window.minimize()` to actually minimize it,  instead of `window.restore()`

The restore method used to return the previous state, before minimization

Comment: I was a bit messy in my explanation

I swapped the two console.log (i've done several ctrl + Z), so it keeps the state where "maximize" work, and that's all.

I've tried the minimize method, but not unmaximize, I'll send news when I get home !