# Minimizing apps via nodejs || plain js

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation

I'm currently working on personal automation project and I want to add 'minimize app' feature.
For example: When I click button, I want to minimize the current browser. I already have window.close(); but this will close the app definitly. I found things like window.minimalize(); or window.minimize();, but none of them worked for me. So is there a way to minimize app?

Edited: It does not have to be only client-side JS, it can be used as terminal based nodejs app. Ex: I type minimize Google Chrome, and it will minimize it.

Comment: This might be [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696350/electron-how-to-minimize-a-window-from-a-rendered-process). In a nutshell, there's no way to do that from client-side JS (for security concerns at least), but there might be options depending on which tool you're running to control the browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Google search for `how to minimize browser` gives the following result:

```
There is no way to minimize the browser window within javascript. No, there isn't. However, depending on what you're doing and which browsers you're targeting, you could play around with the blur and focus events of the window to achieve similar effect.
```

Alternatively, if such control is required, you could always port your code to `Electron.js` or `Neutrino.js`, which were made to let you create desktop applications using JavaScript.

Maybe if you post some code and give us a train of thought to follow, we could work something out.